# C - strtok does strange things

Tags: c++, arrays, character, strtok

i use strtok to split a string into different pieces and assemble them as a struct. This is my code:

```
object* parseJSON(size_t length, char* json, size_t jsonLen){
char *finalString = prepareJSON(json,jsonLen);

cout << finalString << "\n";

char delimiter[] = ",:";
char *token = strtok(finalString, delimiter);

object *retObj = (struct object *)malloc(length);
size_t returnObjectIndex = 0;

size_t index = 0;
bool firstTime = true;
struct object item;

while(token != NULL){
    if((index % 2) != 0){
        if(firstTime){
            item.Type = token;
            firstTime = false;
        } else {
            item.ID = token;
            retObj[returnObjectIndex] = item;
            returnObjectIndex++;
            firstTime = true;
        }
    }
    token = strtok(NULL,delimiter);
    index++;
}

return retObj;
```

}

This is the `finalString`:

> Type:temp,id:3,Type:temp,id:1

In my mind this should come out with this code:

```
for(int n = 0; n < 5; n++){
    cout << returnObject[n].Type << " " << returnObject[n].ID << "\n";
}
```

as:

> temp 3
>   temp 1

but instead i get this on the console:

> temp 3
>   temp 1
>   h"° Ó*°
>   C

Is this because i loop 5 times even though there should be only 2 elements in the array? I loop 5 times because i can't get the number of elements of the array in the pointer (atleast i think that this is not possible).

Any help is very much appreciated

Best regards

Edit: This is my `prepareJSON` function:

```
char* prepareJSON(char* json, size_t jsonLen){
char forbiddenChars[] = {'[', '{','\"', '}', ']'};
bool isForbbidenChar = false;
char* finalString = (char*)malloc(jsonLen);
size_t finalStringIndex = 0;
for(size_t i = 0; i < jsonLen; i++){
    char c = json[i];
    isForbbidenChar = false;
    for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        if(c == forbiddenChars[k]){
            isForbbidenChar = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(isForbbidenChar){
        continue;
    }
    else{
        finalString[finalStringIndex] = c;
        finalStringIndex++;
    }
}

return finalString;
```

}

and this my `main` function:

```
int main(){
object *returnObject;
char json[] = "[{\"Type\":\"temp\",\"id\":\"3\"},{\"Type\":\"temp\",\"id\":\"1\"}]";
returnObject = parseJSON(5,json, strlen(json));
for(int n = 0; n < 5; n++){
    cout << returnObject[n].Type << " " << returnObject[n].ID << "\n";
}
```

}

Solution:

I did indeed allocate too little memory, changed it:

```
object *retObj = (struct object *)malloc(sizeof(struct object) * length);
```

Now it works!

Comment: The most likely answer is that whatever prepareJSON() returns has been overwritten or destroyed. A [mcve] is required for an authoritative answer. This code is quite ugly. Lack of bounds checking everywhere, magical constants, etc...

Comment: Are you sure you allocate enough memory with this? `object *retObj = (struct object *)malloc(length);`

Comment: ...and even when you have corrected that, you are not checking `returnObjectIndex < length`.

Comment: I am sorry that this code is ugly but it is basically my first try with C. @WeatherVane
Thanks a lot! That`s the solution, i fixed my code (edited).

Comment: @binaryBigInt Why are you using `malloc` in a C++ program?  Why not simply `std::string`?  Also, you should read `C++` books and material, not `C` material if your goal is to write a C++ program.

Comment: @binaryBigInt In addition, you really should be using a JSON library that already is aware of how to successfully parse JSON.  The reason is that there are cases where your code will not work correctly, corner cases you haven't considered, etc.  That's why there are libraries to do this kind of work -- because doing this "by hand" is not trivial and is error prone.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is a C program, not C++. I just added `C++` to keywords because i though this post would get more attention, sorry :(
I wrote my own `JSON` parser because i use this on a embedded device and i want to reduce the amount of code size. I don't need a complete JSON parser because in my usecase the json string doesn't change in structure but only in size. I googled around but i found nothing short and  understandable (for me).

Comment: @binaryBigInt *i found nothing short and understandable (for me)* -- The job of a library is to make the interface to it easy for the user to use.  What happens internally is not what you should be concerned with.  Of course it will be difficult to understand if you went into the library's internals, since it takes a lot of sophistication to make an easy to use interface.